# Reskinning Cocos2d iOS/iphone/ipad app : Cant replace images with TexturePacker

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker

I have source code of a iOS game built in cocos2d and working on reskinning it.
Optimized sprite sheets are made by [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) which are generated by script and are taken from .plist file.

[image]

While reskining app, i have replaced these images from the app folder,but after running app older images displayed in app.
 Normal images (which are not optimised via TexturePacker) such as background , icon files are reflecting properly.

Also while compiling app i am getting following error but app runs displaying older images: :

```
       /WORK/App_Name/PackTextures.sh: line 12: /usr/local/bin/TexturePacker: 
No such file or directory

    /WORK/App_Name/PackTextures.sh: line 19: /usr/local/bin/TexturePacker: 
No such file or directory

    /WORK/App_Name/PackTextures.sh: line 26: /usr/local/bin/TexturePacker: 
No such file or directory
```

file "PackTextures.sh" is present in mentioned directory.
My question is:
How to replace images used by TexturePacker or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't say your script is missing, it tells you that there is no program `TexturePacker` in the `/usr/local/bin` folder:

```
/usr/local/bin/TexturePacker: No such file or directory
```

You may on occasion have to delete the app from the device/simulator to force Xcode to transfer the entire app. Sometimes Xcode just doesn't catch up replacing all assets, though if I remember correctly this is mostly related to deleting files from the app.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for pointing on the error , actually i dont have TexturePacker installed.
installed command line tool for TexturePacker at path /usr/local/bin/ resolved issue.

Comment: found it... for future users...
 Try this.

Go to texture packer (I am using free version)
Click texture packer on the menu and select install command line
Grab the default pathname where texture packer was installed. (In my case /usr/bin/TexturePacker)
Update PackTextures.sh to TP="/usr/bin/TexturePacker"